# Select data from 2 mysql tables in Jquery EasyUI

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-easyui

hi im new on using jquery easyui.
i create 3 files, project.php, projectdetail.php and get_project_detail.php

here is my code of **project.php**

```
...
...
<table id="dg" title="Next Target" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:700px;height:automatic" 
            url="get_project_nt.php"
            pagination="true"
            rownumbers="true"
            fitColumns="true"
            singleSelect="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th formatter="formatProjectId" width="165" sortable="true" field="projectname">Project Name</th>
                <th width="100" sortable="true" field="target">Target End Of 2014</th>
                <th width="100" sortable="true" field="PIC">PIC</th>
                <th width="75" sortable="true" field="begindate">Begin</th>
                <th width="75" sortable="true" field="enddate">End</th>
                <th formatter="formatProgress" width="150" sortable="true" field="progress">Progress</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
...
...
<script type="text/javascript">
    function formatProjectId(val,row){
    var url = "projectdetail.php?id=";
    return '<a href="'+url + row.projectname+'">'+val+'</a>';
    }
    </script>
```

i use **formatter ="formatProjectId"** to throw the id value to file projectdetail.php

and this is file **projectdetail.php**

```
...
...
<?
include 'conn.php';
$query = "SELECT * FROM project WHERE projectname ='".$_GET['id']."'";
$hasil = mysql_query($query);
while ($data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil))
{
   echo"<table>";
   echo "<tr><td>Nama project</td> <td>:</td><td>$data[projectname]</td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><td>Target End of</td> <td>:</td><td>$data[target]</td></tr>";
   echo "<tr><td>Last Update</td> <td>:</td><td>$data[lastupdate]</td></tr>";
   echo"</table>";
    ?>
</table>
    <table id="dg" title="All Project" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:automatic;height:automatic" 
            url="get_project_detail.php"
            toolbar="#toolbar" 
            pagination="true"
            rownumbers="true"
            fitColumns="true"
            singleSelect="true">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th width="165" sortable="true" field="projectactivity">Project Activity</th>
                <th width="100" sortable="true" field="target">Target</th>
                <th width="100" sortable="true" field="actual">Actual</th>
                <th width="75" sortable="true" field="problemident">Problem Identification</th>
                <th width="75" sortable="true" field="correctiveact">Corrective Action</th>
                <th width="75" sortable="true" field="duedate">Due Date</th>
                <th width="75" sortable="true" field="PIC">PIC</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
...
...
```

and this is file **get_project_detail.php**

```
<?php 
$page = isset($_POST['page']) ? intval($_POST['page']) : 1;
$rows = isset($_POST['rows']) ? intval($_POST['rows']) : 10;
$sort = isset($_POST['sort']) ? strval($_POST['sort']) : 'projectactivity';
$order = isset($_POST['order']) ? strval($_POST['order']) : 'asc';
$projectname = isset($_POST['projectname']) ? mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['projectname']) : '';
$offset = ($page-1)*$rows;
$result = array();  
include 'conn.php';
$where = "projectactivity like '%$projectname%'";
$rs = mysql_query("select count(*) from dproject");
$row = mysql_fetch_row($rs);
$result["total"] = $row[0];
$rs = mysql_query("select * from dproject where " . $where . " order by $sort $order limit $offset,$rows");
$items = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)){
    array_push($items, $row);
}
$result["rows"] = $items;
echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

this is the database table :

**project**

idproject

category

projectname

target

PIC

emailpic

begindate

enddate

progress

**dproject**

iddproject

idproject

projectactivity

target

actual

problemident

correctiveact

duedate

PIC

we can see 2 table in file **projectdetail.php**
first table takes data from table **project** on database and second table takes data from table **dproject** on database.
first table is success to take data based on **id** that sent from file **project.php**.
but on second table i want to take data from table **dproject** based on the same id between **project** and **dproject** may be like this **project.idproject=dproject.idproject** but its not working. Would everybody explain to me where is my wrong code ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing that you want to display as subgrid, is that correct?
Easyui has this feature, you can use this easyly, please take a look at the tutorial, and see the demo.

http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid22.php

You can use this as reference for understanding structure files:

1. Primary file for table, ex: project_list.php (output are html, body table generate grid)
2. File for get data project_data_json.php (output are json encoded)
3. File for get second db grid the project detail list, ex: project_detail_json.php (output are json encoded)

Look at the sample code onExpandrow, you should link to project_detail_json.php
Don't forget you should download the js file here http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/datagrid-detailview.js